# Character Encoding Issue With JMS Mail Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, mail-server

I have an issue while sending an email using JMS when the content has accented characters.

The message is pushed on to the queue and placed as an object message. The listener listens to the message and delivers it to the mail server.

Everything works fine on my local server. However when I run the same on Solaris production server, the accent characters are getting messed up. Within the email content, it prints De Le�n for De León. Basically, accent characters are not getting encoded and displays a question mark [�].

Any help on this issue is highly appreciated. Below is the code that I use to deliver the messages.

```
private void sendEmailMessage(EmailBean emailBean) {
    System.out.println("SendReceivedEmailMessages::sendEmail()");
    try {

        if (emailBean.getFromAddresses() != null && !emailBean.getFromAddresses().isEmpty()) {
            Properties existingProperties = session.getProperties();
            existingProperties.put("mail.from", emailBean.getFromAddresses());
            session = Session.getInstance(existingProperties);
        }

        String DELIMITER = ";";
        String subject = emailBean.getSubject();
        String msgText = emailBean.getBody();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(message, "text/html");


        InternetAddress[] toAddressList = parseRecipients(emailBean.getToAddresses(), DELIMITER);
        InternetAddress[] ccAddressList = parseRecipients(emailBean.getCcAddresses(), DELIMITER);
        InternetAddress[] bccAddressList = parseRecipients(emailBean.getBccAddresses(), DELIMITER);

        message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddressList);
        message.addRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddressList);
        message.addRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddressList);

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        if (emailBean.getFileByteArrRegular() != null) {
            addAttachmentFiles(multipart, emailBean.getFileByteArrRegular(), emailBean.getFilename() + "_Regular.docx", msgText);
        }
        if (emailBean.getFileByteOthers() != null) {
            addAttachmentFiles(multipart, emailBean.getFileByteOthers(), emailBean.getFilename() + ".docx", msgText);
        } else {
            addAttachmentFiles(multipart, null, null, msgText);
        }

        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SendReceiveEmailMessages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        Logger.getLogger(SendReceiveEmailMessages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getStackTrace()[0].toString(), ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SendReceiveEmailMessages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        Logger.getLogger(SendReceiveEmailMessages.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getStackTrace()[0].toString(), ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is most likely in the code that calls `emailBean.setBody(messageBody)`, because your message body has already been encoded at that point.

Comment: Hmmm.... EmailBean is a simple pojo with 'private String body;' variable. So it is just the html text in string format that I am setting to the body variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it might help others:

```
message.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

The above code change fixed my issue.